# Calculating the global optimum

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

In a problem I need to approximate a vector $W \in \Bbb{R}^n$ with a binary vector $B \in  \{-1,1\}^n$ as $W \approx \alpha B + \gamma1$ for $\alpha\ge0$ and $\gamma\in$ $\Bbb{R}$. To find an optimal estimation, the
following optimization is solved:

$\min_{\alpha,B,\gamma}  \| W - (\alpha B + \gamma1)\|_2^2$ $\  $ s.t. $\ $$B \in  \{-1,1\}^n$, $\alpha\ge0$, $\gamma\in$ $\Bbb{R}$

by expanding the objective we have:

J($\alpha$,$B$,$\gamma$) = $\| W - (\alpha B + \gamma1)\|_2^2$ = $W^TW - 2\alpha W^TB - 2\gamma W^T + \alpha^2B^TB + 2\alpha\gamma B^T1 + \gamma^21^T1$

where the first term is not dependent on optimization variables and since $B \in  \{-1,1\}^n$,  $B^TB = n$.  Also $1^T1 = n$. Thus the objective is:

F($\alpha$,$B$,$\gamma$) = $ -2\alpha W^TB - 2\gamma W^T + \alpha^2n + 2\alpha\gamma B^T1 + \gamma^2n$

for minimization of F, we first consider $\gamma$ to be fixed and K($\alpha,B$) = $\alpha^2n - 2\alpha(W^T-\gamma1^T)B$ is minimized. As the $\alpha$ is positive, it is enough to maximize ($W^T-\gamma 1^T)B$. Thus, the optimal solution for $B$ is:

$B^* = sign(W-\gamma 1)$.

By taking the derivative of K with respect to $\alpha$ and set it to zero and using $B^*$, we obtain the solution for $\alpha$ as:

$\alpha^*$$ = $$1\over{n}$$\|W-\gamma 1\|_1$

and based on these solutions we can calculate $\gamma$. Finally we iteratively compute these variables until convergence. However, this approach can only converge to local minimum of F($\alpha$,$B$,$\gamma$).

Is there a way to calculate globally optimal solution for this optimization problem?

<< Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. >>

Comment: How big is $n$?

Comment: $n$ is for example in range 50 ~ 100

Comment: Note that $$W - (\alpha B + \gamma)$$ is a **type error**, as it adds a scalar to an $n$-dimensional vector.

Answer (score 1):

The extra treatment of $\gamma{\bf 1}$ unduly complicates the process without providing more degrees of freedom. Note that for any $\lambda$, $\mu\in{\mathbb R}$, where $\lambda\leq \mu$, one has
$$\lambda(1,0)+\mu(0,1)={\mu-\lambda\over2}(-1,1)+{\lambda+\mu\over2}(1,1)\ ,$$
hence ${\mu-\lambda\over2}\geq0$ can stand in for $\alpha$ and ${\lambda+\mu\over2}$ for $\gamma$. The same is true if $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are replaced by $(1^r,0^s)$ and $(0^r,1^s)$, where $1^r=\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_r$.

In order to find the optimal approximation to the given $W$ we therefore assume that $W_1\leq W_2\leq\ldots\leq W_n$ and look for an approximant vector of the form $(\lambda,\ldots,\lambda,\mu,\ldots,\mu)$ with a suitable number of $\lambda$s and $\mu$s. To this end choose an $r\in[n-1]$ and minimize
$$Q_r:=\sum_{i=1}^r(\lambda-W_i)^2+\sum_{i=r+1}^n(\mu-W_i)^2\ .$$
This leads to
$$\lambda={1\over r}\sum_{i=1}^r W_i,\qquad \mu={1\over n-r}\sum_{i=r+1}^nW_i\ ,$$
and then to a simple formula for  ${\rm min}_{\lambda,\>\mu}\> Q_r$.
It remains to determine the optimal $r$. This can be done using binary search in $O(\log n)$ steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to formulate the optimal $r$ according to some properties of $W$?

Comment: $W$ has no "properties", it is just a set of random real data.The problem is to separate these into two clusters in an optimal way. I'm sure this is a standard problem in applied statistics. – My next move would be: What happens numerically when $r$ is increased by $1$?